# Amazon Simple Notification Service is RESTFUL web service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Is Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) RESTFUL web service?

On reading [Amazon SNS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/Welcome.html), there is nothing written about RESTFUL service.

Thanks

Comment: No, it's not RESTFUL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking some request examples and as far as I know it's not REST, as it's not using resources in the url, only parameters.

Examples:

Create topic

```
 http://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
  ?Name=My-Topic
  &Action=CreateTopic
  &SignatureVersion=2
  &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
  &Timestamp=2010-03-31T12%3A00%3A00.000Z
  &AWSAccessKeyId=(AWS Access Key ID)
  &Signature=gfzIF53exFVdpSNb8AiwN3Lv%2FNYXh6S%2Br3yySK70oX4%3
```

Add Permission:

```
  http://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
  ?TopicArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aus-east-1%3A123456789012%3AMy-Test
  &ActionName.member.1=Publish
  &ActionName.member.2=GetTopicAttributes
  &Label=NewPermission
  &AWSAccountId.member.1=987654321000
  &AWSAccountId.member.2=876543210000
  &Action=AddPermission
  &SignatureVersion=2
  &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
  &Timestamp=2010-03-31T12%3A00%3A00.000Z
  &AWSAccessKeyId=(AWS Access Key ID)
  &Signature=k%2FAU%2FKp13pjndwJ7rr1sZszy6MZMlOhRBCHx1ZaZFiw%3D
```

More info: http://aws.amazon.com/en/sns/faqs/

Answer (score 2):

It isn't RESTful as it is not using resources in the endpoint(s).